# Do I need Git to use Github in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA has 2 plugins: **Git** and **Github**. Do I need to install Git from http://git-scm.com on my local windows machine in order to upload my files to GitHub through IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I just came up against the same problem.

If you choose not to do the full PATH (environment variable) integration when install git (on Windows) you'll need to tell IntelliJ where to find `git.cmd`; you can do this in

```
Settings > Project Settings > Version Control > VCSs > Git
```

**Example** in my case it was portable git looks like this on windows

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d7effa1a4a322478cd29c826b52a0c118ad3db11\cmd\git.exe

Comment: Ah, yes.  That's a much better answer!  I installed git from http://msysgit.github.com/ and then registered it like that.

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Settings > Project Settings > Version Control > git

Path to Git executeable : D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it looks like you need to have git installed on your machine.  I just tried to clone a project on github, and I got:

```
Cannot run program "git.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Steve\Code"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: So what's the solution to that? :O

Comment: @RainbowHat Install command line version of git.  Or, if you already have command line git installed, point IntelliJ to that exe.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell IntelliJ where to find `git.exe`. This can be done by going into:

```
Configure->Settings->Version Control->Git->Path to Git Excetuable
```

Changing the path to something like this:

```
C:\Users\***YOUR_USER_NAME***\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565cb218a521411d0e854079a28c\cmd\git.exe`
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you have to install Git first. [git-for-windows.github.io](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) is OK. Then

```
Configure->Settings->Version Control->Git-><browse for git.exe>
```