# After installing IntelliJ Idea, I cannot use GitHub and Git because of missing "git.exe" file

Tags: intellij-idea

Found a reason and solution.

When I was installin Idea, git was already installed on my computer, so Idea haven't installed over existing one.

To solve this problem, fist find "git.exe" file on your computer using operating system's search. 
After you've found it, go to File>Settings>Version Controls>Git (even if you're having problem with GitHub) >Path to git executable > "..." and paste the destination path of your git.exe file that you have found erlier.

Comment: That's good if you want to share info in a Q&A manner, but post the solution part as an answer to your question. Anyway I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581832/do-i-need-git-to-use-github-in-jetbrains-intellij-idea#7442106

Answer (score 0):

If you choose not to do the full PATH (environment variable) integration when installing `git` (on Windows), you'll need to tell IntelliJ where to find `git.cmd;`, you can do this in

```
Settings > Project Settings > Version Control > VCSs > Git
```