# GitHub Repository is exist, but there is no repository in GitHub repo list

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm newbie on gitHub.. so i don't know deeply about git yet.

I create repository in gitHub, using intellij commit. (I think it is my fault..)

And commit is done, but in gitHub, what i committing repository is invisible.

So i create New repo in gitHub, but to same name, and git say there is exist repo.

But interesting thing is that when i refresh browser, sometime repo is visible.

[image]

That is one of my invisible repo.

And i click that repo, gitHub says 404 not found, and when back to prev page, that repo is invisible again.

I want to permanently delete all invisible repository.

Is any one know about this please answer me.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub is undergoing maintenance. Take a look at this: https://status.github.com/messages

Comment: I think it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

can you read and try this link ? I think your error, intellij can't connect to github
[Do I need Git to use Github in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581832/do-i-need-git-to-use-github-in-jetbrains-intellij-idea)

Comment: yap. I checking all of that conditions.. but another repo is have same problem too.
It's looks like gitHub's error.